# passive form: when to use to be

Tags: passive-voice

I came across a sentence that read 
'It was the first to be sold online'. It used the passive voice. Why not 'first sold online'? Why is to be used here and when do we use to be in the passive?
Thanks

Comment: In your context, ***to be*** is effectively optional. But *semantically*, if not syntactically, it could also  be directly replaced by alternatives such as *...the first **that was** sold online*. It's in the passive because the *subject* of TO SELL isn't specified. Active would have to be something like *Online booksellers sold it first*, but there's considerable ambiguity about exactly what that might mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When it's optional, it's not the passive voice of a verb, it's a past participle functioning as an adjective. One could transform it into a subordinate clause "that was sold online"; in this case, it again becomes a full-fledged verb.

Answer (score 1):

"Sold online" without the verb "to be" (in its appropriate form) is not the passive voice. It is a past participle, which, on its own, functions as an adjective.

The verb "was" in the beginning of the sentence is **not** tied to "sold online", so it is not part of the passive.

Compare the following sentences,

> — He **was the first** *to notice* that something was wrong.
>
> — From all the children in the family, April **was the first** one *to open* her Christmas presents.

As you see, here we are simply talking about someone being "the first (one)" **to do** something.

So we are dealing with the following construction,

> to be the first (one) + Infinitive

In your sentence, something was the first..... **to be sold** (which is the Infinitive form of a passive construction).

The first "was" has nothing to do with "sold", it is tied to "the first" (to be the first). So, in order for there to be a passive after that, that passive must contain the verb "to be" in some form.